# Is there a way to delete objects from database without locking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an object with one-to-many relationship and cascade delete rule. Deleting of this object initiates deleting of many related objects (30 000 and more). When I save context after deleting, it takes impermissible amout of time (dozens of seconds, maybe a minute). Furthermore, when I try to fetch some data when context has not finished saving yet - I get a lock.
The app uses only one context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. Is there a way to save context after deleting objects, and be able to fetch data at the same time? Is there any techniques with multiple contexsts or even coordinators?

Comment: Using multiple contexts, yes. What percentage of the objects in the store are you deleting here?

Comment: @Wain, it is not defined. It may be a half of the whole db, or 5%.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: enable WAL, save in batches, and maybe try different contexts and/or persistent store coordinators.

There are different levels of locks in Core Data. There is a lock on a context level. If a context is used in several places and one place works with a context, other places wait. One might even not call it a lock, but just normal usage of the context. If the context is of confinement (traditional) type, it must be used either from one thread or from a serial queue. So, serially. If it is on one of queue concurrency types, those queues are also serial, just managed for us by Core Data.

Then there is a lock on the persistent store coordinator level. If two contexts use the same persistent store coordinator and one context is used in a way that requires persistent store coordinator’s work, other context waits. From the locking perspective this is more efficient then having only one context, but you need to merge data between contexts back and forth.

Then there is a lock on a database file itself. If several persistent store coordinators are used, and some job requires working with the persistent store, another coordinator and all its contexts wait. But if it doesn’t require the store, they don’t wait. This is the best design for avoiding locks, but it also comes with a cost. Firstly, you again need to merge changes between contexts. But this is actually pretty usual thing in most Core Data apps. But secondly, when having two persistent store coordinators you have two separate caches. And this can be very inconvenient sometimes. I would even say it’s a pain in the ass.

And speaking about SQLite, you can enable WAL that should allow readers to work concurrently with writers.

Also there is a recommendation from Apple to save in batches when you need to save big amount of data.

I would personally recommend the following combination.

1. Enable WAL on SQLite.
2. Use one persistent store coordinator.
3. Use two contexts for not huge tasks. The “main” one is of private queue concurrency type. Is is configured with persistent store coordinator. It will allow you to do background saves, but not for large amounts of data. The second context will be for the UI. It will be configured with the first one as a parent and of main queue concurrency type.
4. Create additional context for the big updates. Configure it with the same persistent store coordinator. When saving, save in batches.
5. Merge changes between contexts as needed.

Using different contexts will allow you not to lock on a context level. By using single persistent store coordinator you’ll benefit from having single cache. And by enabling WAL you’ll reduce locking on the file level.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Can you please explain, how do I save deleted objects in batches? Should I only delete small chunk of objects at a time, then save context, and so on?
And btw, what is the way to merge contexts after such operation - handle ContextDidSaveNotification, or maybe post my own notification after deletion is complete?

Comment: You’ll basically have some loop somewhere that iterates the objects you need to save. And every, for example, 400 or 1000 you call save. But the setup I described might work for you even without saving in batches.

Comment: The most straightforward way to merge changes into other contexts is to subscribe to did-save notification and then use the merge method. It is important to call the merge method in a queue or thread of the target context (normal Core Data threading rules). However sometimes you don’t need all the changes from the big background update. For example, when there is fetched results controller that will replay all those changes. In those cases one might just refetch what’s needed instead of merging.

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: Practically no. When I merge changes after huge deletion from temporary context, it takes some time (lesser than saving, but still significant) during which I can't access DB, and when I save then main context - it also takes time. I have enabled WAL, but haven't noticed any differences while accessing DB. I think, although WAL should allow readers to work concurrently with writers, Core Data locks context to preserve consistency. The only way imho, is to delete objects on main context and lock UI until it ends, because actually user can't do anything without accessing DB, which gets locked.

Comment: Then the amount of changes in the background context is huge, it is often more efficient to just refetch in the UI context instead of merging. Imagine you’re having fetched results controller and your table view displays only first 10 results. If you merge, fetched results controller will replay all those changes in the UI context. But if you just refetch (especially with fetch batch size), you’ll fetch for only what’s needed.